# How to clear calendar cache?

Tags: macos, calendar, google

I'm trying to clear the cache of my calendar, since I'm having trouble with calendar notifications after connecting to a Google Calendar.

One of the recommended solutions is to clear the Calendar cache as described here
http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-the-iCal-Cache

However, within my Library folder I cannot find the suggested subfolders

```
~/Library/Calendars/
~/Library/Caches/
```

in which I would find

```
~/Library/Calendars/Calendar Cache
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.iCal
```

Are such folders now in a different location? Or are they hidden somehow? (I'm using OS X Maverics 10.9.4.)

Any hints would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: In Mavericks and Yosemite you should still have a `~/Library/Calendars` with a `Calendar Cache` cache file (and more) in it. I can confirm that `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.iCal` is gone at least with Yosemite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the caches folder here (I’m not sure if the path is always the same or is unique for each OS X, consider digging through `/var/folders/th/` if you can’t find it. Or use application such as [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to reveal the caches folders:

```
/var/folders/th/k1mj9dgx0xddk2mcl_p1707r0000gn/C/com.apple.iCal
/var/folders/th/k1mj9dgx0xddk2mcl_p1707r0000gn/C/com.apple.iCal.CalendarNC
```

Answer (score 1):

Just learned that the Library files are hidden in the most recent versions of OSX.  To see them, open Finder, then click simultaneously on the Go tab and the Option key.  As long as they are held down, a new item (Library) will appear.  Go down to it and you will find your file.  Or you can open Finder, select the Go tab, then the Go to Folder item, and insert ~/Library.  Not exactly user intuitive.  Unfortunately, Apple is becoming more like Microsoft in terms of usability.